# Connection between 5 books of the Torah and the 5 Megillot?

Tags: tanach, commentaries, megillat-esther

The megillot are read on different occasions in the year:

- Shir HaShirim on Pesach
- Rut on Shavuot
- Eicha on Tisha b'Av
- Kohelet on Sukkot
- Esther on Purim

Do any mefarshim find a connection between the 5 megillot and the 5 books of the Torah?

Comment: 5 megillot is not a halachic category. They are just 5 books some read on various occasions. A better parallel is 5 books of tehillim.

Comment: @DoubleAA what’s the 5 books of tehillim?

Comment: @Curious https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22856/759