# Source for book of Tehillim out of order?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, tehilim-psalms

I recall learning a midrash (shochar tov?) that the book of Tehillim is out of order and Rebbi Yehoshua ben Levi wanted to put it back in order but was not allowed to do so. Where is this statement found?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/tehilim-hachida-in-the-order-of-the-aleph-bais

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15450/the-order-of-tehillim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Midrash Tehillim on mizmor 3 - see it [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14295&st=&pgnum=164&hilite=)

3 lines from the top of the page.

> דבר אחר מזמור לדוד בברחו. זהו שאמר הכתוב לא ידע אנוש ערכה
>    איוב כח יג), אמר רבי אלעזר לא ניתנו פרשיותיה של תורה על הסדר,
>    שאס ניתנו על חםדר, כל מי שהוא קןרא בהם היה יכול להחיות מתים, ולעשות
>    מופתים, לכך נתעלמה סדורה של תורה וכו

The parshiyos of the Torah were not given in order

> ר' י הושע בן לוי בקש לישב על הספר הזה

R' Yehoshua ben Levy wished to resolve this book (Tehillim).

Referring to Tehillim, continuing on the point above that the Torah was not given in order, the Midrash says that R' Yehoshua wanted to fix it.