# Torah out of order and the resurrection

Tags: sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms, pentateuch-chumash, resurrection-of-the-dead

I remember reading once that the Torah (Pentateuch) is not in the correct order and if someone knew the correct order he would have the ability to do techias hameisim (resurrection).  The exact wording I don't remember - eg if it was he would have the ability - or it would cause, etc.  The basic idea being that 1) the Torah was not in the "correct" order and 2) the correct order was related to the resurrection.

I've asked several talmidei chochomim and they vaguely remember such a concept but don't know a source.  One person I asked said he had heard the concept with respect to Tehillim, but not Torah (see [Source for book of Tehillim out of order?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/source-for-book-of-tehillim-out-of-order))

Does anyone know a source for this concept?

Comment: Perhaps re: resurrection, he meant the correct order was unknowable.  Since no man has the ability to do the resurrection (except for navi or the mashiach), so no man knows the order: if he did, he would not just be a man, but maybe malach or navi.

Comment: thanks for reminding I asked this question - I found a (partial) source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Yalkut Shimoni on Tehillim 625.1](http://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.625.1-627.1) Rebbe Elazar says this:

> א"ר אלעזר לא נתנו פרשיות התורה על הסדר שאלמלי נתנו על הסדר כל מי שהיה קורא בהן היה יכול להחיות מתים ולעשות מופתים לפיכך נתעלם סדורה של תורה, והוא גלוי לפני הקב"ה שנאמר ומי כמוני יקרא

Answer (score 2):

Someone sent me a reference to this from Mafteach HaSefirot from Avraham Abulafia (I didn't see it inside - he sent me the text below):

ואמנם לפי הדרך העמוקה האחרת, והיא היות כל התורה שמותיו של הקב"ה, אין באלה חסרון ולא באלה תוספת. אבל כל אות ואות הוא עולם בפני עצמו שלם. **וכבר אמרו ז"ל שאם היתה התורה כתובה כסדר היה אדם יכול להחיות מתים**. והעלימה השם בסדרה מפני פריצי הדורות וגלה אותה למי שראוי להחיות בה מתים.

It seems from his reference, Abulafia is quoting some other Chazal.  I don't know that source.

Comment: How does that answer the question? it should be part of the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: I heard a "shmuah" - something someone said to me.  But maybe I dreamt it... maybe the person was mistaken.  I was looking for where this was written so I could give it over with some confidence.  Here is a source that says what I was looking for.  It claims it's not the original source, but this is something I can rely on to quote and give over. I would prefer to find the original source, but this is a source  and Abulafia is generally considered a respected source (depending on which circles you're talking to.)